# Resolving an "edit war"?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have a long-lived [Community Wiki answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4525/list-of-average-genre-tempo-bpm-levels/4563#4563) which has had many useful improvements from many users.

But there's a disagreement about the *true* tempo of **Dubstep**. An early addition listed it as 140 BPM. A later edit explain that it should be considered to be half that tempo although there many be a double-speed section which can be counted as 140.

Now there's a [suggested edit which reverses the claim.](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/36794) I mostly consider it a good edit because it's adding information that was not there before. But on this point, the new material doesn't address the divergence of opinion for which the "half-tempo" editor at least offered an explanation.

Thoughts? ... Approve the edit? ... Approve but restore some of the alternate opinion? ... Research Dubstep and try to form my own opinion? (while tempting, this last option suggests a great investment of time).

Comment: It appears to be both (from Googling). The answer should reflect that - that's the best way to deal with it.

Comment: I thought the "slow" parts of dubstep were clearly half time feel, but not a tempo change. Shrug.